# MongoDB query of array of documents returning all elements

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, geojson

I have a collection called 'cupcakes' that was loaded from a GeoJSON file using **mongoimport**. The GeoJSON can be found [here](https://github.com/lyzidiamond/learn-geojson/blob/master/geojson/cupcakes.geojson?short_path=4360989), and is a known valid JSON file. This part seems to have gone to plan, and doing:

```
use cupcakes
db.cupcakes.find({ })
```

This pulls back all the features as expected. However, I am trying to do a query that will return only the features that have gluten free set to "no".

I have tried the instructions as per the documentation around querying [arrays of documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-an-array-of-documents).

```
 db.cupcakes.find({features: { $elemMatch: { "properties.gluten free":"no"}}}).pretty()
```

But as far as I can tell this appears to be returning **all** of the features as opposed to **just** those that are gluten free establishments.

Essentially I am wanting to pull back all the features where "properties.gluten free" of the features is set to "no" (or "yes" for that matter).

A sample output might be:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -122.70069837570189,
            45.53570881624427
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "Le Cookie Monkey",
        "address": "1902 NW 24th Avenue",
        "website": "http://www.lecookiemonkey.com/",
        "gluten free": "no",
        "open1": "Tuesday - Friday, 9am - 3pm",
        "open2": "Saturday, 9am - 2pm"
    }
},
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -122.6375323534012,
            45.5219957171348
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "Crema Coffee + Bakery",
        "address": "2728 SE Ankeny Street",
        "website": "http://www.cremabakery.com/",
        "gluten free": "no",
        "open1": "Monday - Sunday, 7am - 6pm"
    }
},
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -122.60960519313811,
            45.472775425296014
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "Mehri's Bakery & Deli",
        "address": "6923 SE 52nd Avenue",
        "website": "http://www.mehris.com/",
        "gluten free": "no",
        "open1": "Monday - Friday, 7am - 7pm",
        "open2": "Saturday, 8am - 5pm",
        "open3": "Sunday, 8am - 2pm"
    }
},
```

... and so on until all the features where "gluten free" : "no" are returned.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the **[`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/projection/positional/)** operator in your projection which limits the contents of the `features` array from the query results to contain only the first element matching the query document as follows:

```
db.cupcakes.find(
    { "features.properties.gluten free": "no" },
    { "features.$": 1, "_id": 0 }
);
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "features" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    -122.653357386589, 
                    45.51208367658516
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "name" : "Hungry Heart Cupcakes",
                "address" : "1212 SE Hawthorne Boulevard",
                "website" : "http://www.hungryheartcupcakes.com",
                "gluten free" : "no",
                "open1" : "Monday - Sunday, 11am - 9pm"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To pull back all the features where gluten free is equal to no, the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** pipeline operator in the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** should work for you in this case. This will recursively descend through the document structure and do some actions based on an evaluation of specified conditions at each level. The **[`map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)** method will then produce the final array of objects as per expectation. The concept can be a bit tricky to grasp but the following example demonstrates this:

```
db.cupcakes.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { "features.properties.gluten free" : "no" }
    },
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$eq": [ "$gluten free", "yes" ] 
                },
                "then": "$$PRUNE",
                "else": "$$DESCEND"
            }
        }
    }
]).map(function(doc){ return doc.features; });
```

Comment: Hi @chridam thanks for the reply, insightful. How can I make this pull back all the features where gluten free is equal to no?

Comment: You could use the aggregation framework's **`$redact`** pipeline in that case. See updated answer.

Comment: Hi @chridam thanks, that makes sense, shame it's not baked in... either way the answer you gave is almost there, but it still returns the parent object itself (the feature so to speak) complete with type and geometry. Is there a way to remove that? At the moment only the properties object gets pruned.

Comment: Not too sure if I got your question clearly, would you mind editing your question to include a minimal document example and the exact expected output please?

Comment: Hi Chridam, no problem, one moment.

Comment: I think maybe I am approaching this in the wrong way... perhaps the collection needs to act as the FeatureCollection holding object as per this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101686/what-is-the-best-or-recommended-way-to-store-a-geojson-featurecollection-in-mong

Comment: I've just updated the answer with an approach that I think may work in your favour, if you could give that a go and let me know how it pans out for you.

Comment: Hi Chridam,  still getting the issue where it seems all the features pull through, just some have had the properties removed. Thanks for your help. I am considering taking a different approach to make this simpler!